# Count 30 variables based on condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

Hello guys I am new to R, I basically got a data frame made out of 31 variables (ID, and 30 items coded 1,2,3)

I would like to create a new variable based on a specific condition.. I want to be like this:

(because 2 was present only in those 2 items(item1 and item3), so basically I want to create a new variable showing how many times 2 was selected in those 30 items)

I would really appreciate your help

Best Regards

Comment: Why did you remove the code from the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MrFlick: Using Update1 version does not work as Using `.` in the `rowSums` bypasses the `across()` (see comment MrFlick)

Therefore we could use `rowwise` with `c_across` and `sum` within a dplyr workflow:

Here is an example where `ID == 2`:

****2. Update:****

data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 2L, Item1 = 2L, Item2 = 3L, Item3 = 2L, Item4 = 3L, 
    Newvariable = 2L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Total = sum(c_across(-ID)==2))
```

output:

```
# Rowwise: 
     ID Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Newvariable Total
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>       <int> <int>
1     2     2     3     2     3           2     3
```

**Update1:** **(does not work)**

Using `.` in the `rowSums` bypasses the `across()` (see comment MrFlick)

```
df %>% 
    mutate(across(-ID), Total = rowSums(. == 2))
```

**First answer:**

We could use `rowSums`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Total = rowSums(. == 2))
```

```
  ID Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Newvariable Total
1  1     2     3     2     3           2     3
```

Comment: This would also count 2 if it was in the ID column. Probably not desirable.

Comment: You are right. Please see my update!

Comment: That update doesn't work. Try it with `df <- data.frame(ID=1:2, Item1=c(2,2), Item2=c(1,1))`. Using `.` in the rowSums bypasses the `across()`

Comment: Please see my update!